# "Who sees what" videos on Youtube now mostly private. Other way to view them?

Tags: field-level-security, owd, record-access-level, video, training

Another exam coming up and again I am trying to understand the subtleties of object and record access (for me the most complicated thing in Salesforce). There is an enlightening Salesforce video series on Youtube about this, Who sees what: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6747B4DAE356E17C
But most videos are private now, no longer accessible to me. Does anyone know another way of accessing these videos, via help or training?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some googling: it seems like Salesforce is transferring these videos to something called vidyard. For example, the Overview video is now located on http://salesforce.vidyard.com/watch/kXk6BaNlWJP27UyFO8vNUg, but without links to the other videos. It seems that the videos must now be accessed via help, I found another one in Setting Your Organization-Wide Sharing Defaults: http://salesforce.vidyard.com/watch/4I62yWd-0q-wpv2qR3hyKQ

Some more googling: the URL for the overview video with links to the other 9 videos is http://salesforce.vidyard.com/watch/v66PY49hTxxQiZe1h4RX1A

And another way of accessing them: in the [User Guide](https://na1.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/sf.pdf), the section Video Demos > Security, also lists the complete set of "Who sees what" videos.